# Shell script on mac and ubuntu 14.04: Boolean command line args

Tags: bash, macos, ubuntu

I'm trying to write a generic shell script to archive X days older files matching pattern passed as parameter. I'm having tough time making the boolean parameter<s>, regex parameter and regex variable</s> in script work across mac and ubuntu. I'm new to shell scripting. Any suggestion related to the problem or best practices are welcome. Following is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#Default source dir
SOURCE_DIR=./logs/
# Delete by default
DELETE=YES
# Archive files older by these many days
OLD=7
# Pattern to archive
PATTERN="*.log*"

# Use -gt 1 to consume two arguments per pass in the loop
# (each argument has a corresponding value to go with it).
while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; do
    key="$1"
    case $key in
        -s|--source_dir)
            SOURCE_DIR="$2"
            shift # past argument
            ;;
        -d|--dest_dir)
            DEST_DIR="$2"
            shift # past argument
            ;;
        -o|--days)
            OLD="$2"
            shift # past argument
            ;;
        -p|--pattern)
            PATTERN="$2"
            shift # past argument
            ;;
        -n|--no-delete)
            DELETE=NO
            ;;
        *)
            # unknown option
        ;;
    esac
    shift # past argument or value
done


if [[ ! -d "$SOURCE_DIR" ]]; then
    echo 'Archive source does not exist'
    exit 1
fi
SOURCE_DIR=${SOURCE_DIR%/}

if [[ -z "$DEST_DIR" ]]; then
    DEST_DIR="${SOURCE_DIR%/}/backup"
fi
DEST_DIR=${DEST_DIR%/}

if [[ ! -d "$DEST_DIR" ]]; then
    echo 'Creating destination '$DEST_DIR
    mkdir -p -- "$DEST_DIR"
fi

echo $SOURCE_DIR
echo $DEST_DIR
echo $OLD
echo $PATTERN
echo $DELETE

files=$(find $SOURCE_DIR -mtime +$OLD -type f -name $PATTERN)
echo $files

if [[ $DELETE = YES ]]; then
    echo "Delete files"
else
    echo "Don't delete files"
fi
```

Outpout on Mac:

```
(mysql30):recon-etl anshuc$ ./archive.sh -s junk/ -p *.py -o 10 -n
junk
junk/backup
10
*.py
YES
junk/__init__.py junk/client.py
Delete files
(mysql30):recon-etl anshuc$
```

Output on ubuntu 14.04

```
anshuc:~/workspace/xyz$ ./archive.sh -s ae/tools/ -d ae/logs/backup/ -p *.py -n -o 420
ae/tools
ae/logs/backup
420
*.py
NO
ae/tools/services/__init__.py ae/tools/__init__.py 
Don't delete files
anshuc:~/workspace/xyz$
```

**DELETE not working on mac** is the concern. Also, I was having problem with **PATTERN** argument before. Though on trial and error I have come across a way to do. But am not sure of side-effects in case someone doesn't use quotes or any other intricacies that may be involved. A li'l input on that would make me more knowledged. :-)
TIA

Comment: The question has a "python" tag, probably a mistake.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- questions about code should have a **minimal**, complete, verifiable example. "Minimal" means that code should include only components necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: ...also, you should seriously reconsider your argument-parsing format. [POSIX utility conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html) call for options to come before positional arguments, and for `--` to act as an option terminator, so anything after it is unconditionally positional. If you don't honor either of those, then a file whose name starts with `-` can alter your program's behavior.

Comment: On another point, [POSIX environment variable conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) specify that all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the operating system or shell, and reserves names with at least one lower-case character for application use (guaranteeing that they can be used safely without modifying the behavior of any POSIX-specified utility). Since setting a regular shell variable that uses an environment variable's name will overwrite that environment variable, this convention applies to shell variables, not env vars only.